# TCP Socket communication between processes on Heroku worker dyno

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, heroku, worker

I'd like to know how to communicate between processes on a Heroku worker dyno.

We want a Resque worker to read off a queue and send the data to another process running on the same dyno.  The "other process" is an off-the-shelf piece of software that usually uses TCP sockets (port xyz) to listen for commands.  It is set up to run as a background process before the Resque worker starts.

However, when we try to connect locally to that TCP socket, we get nowhere.

Our Rake task for setting up the queue does this:

```
task "resque:setup" do
  # First launch our listener process in the background
  `./some_process_that_listens_on_port_12345 &`

  # Now get our queue worker ready, set up Redis backing store
  port = 12345
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'  
  ENV['PORT'] = port.to_s
  Resque.redis = ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']

  # Start working from the queue
  WorkerClass.enqueue
end
```

And that works -- our listener process runs, and Resque tries to process queued tasks.  However, the Resque jobs fail because they can't connect to `localhost:12345` (specifically, `Errno::ECONNREFUSED`).

Possibly, Heroku is blocking TCP socket communication on the same dyno.  Is there a way around this?

I tried to take the "code" out of the situation and just executed on the command line (after the server process claims that it is properly bound to 12345):

```
nc localhost 12345 -w 1 </dev/null
```

But this does not connect either.

We are currently investigating changing the client/server code to use `UNIXSocket` on both sides as opposed to `TCPSocket`, but as it's an off-the-shelf piece of software, we'd rather avoid our own fork if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem using Docker containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Fifo?

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FIFO-Special-Files.html#FIFO-Special-Files

Comment: While Neil's answer is the shortest, it was ended up working in the end.  FIFO files (named pipes) allow us to redirect the stdout and stdin of the 2 processes to each other, creating a 2-way communication process w/o doing anything at all with the network layer.  Yes, we've had to open up the source code of the 3rd party lib a bit (something I wanted to avoid), but getting ANY program to listen to stdin is pretty easy!

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding this answer completely.  Are you creating one of these special fifo files on heroku's ephemeral file system?  I thought each dyno/process keeps it's own separate file system, so how are they both connecting to the same file?  Thanks.

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be files - a table in a database or a redis list would suffice as well.

Comment: That's great that FIFO files work, Neil -- thanks for that tip -- but any idea why (Unix) processes on a dyno aren't able to communicate via TCP? I was planning on proxying requests (via [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)) based on hostname to two server (Unix) processes, and indeed, it doesn't work. In cases like this, reworking the proxy and services to use FIFO files instead of TCP/HTTP is way overkill. Anything we can do to support listening on multiple ports (internally) on Heroku? Thanks!

Comment: The main problem is that you have no idea where your other processes are, or even if they exist.  You are operating in an isolated environment.

Answer (score 5):

Use message queue Heroku add-ons ...,

like [IronMQ](https://addons.heroku.com/iron_mq) for exsample

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, you've answered your own question, you cannot connect to localhost 12345.

This way of setting up your processes is a strange one as your running two processes within one Heroku dyno which removes a lot of the benefits of Heroku, i.e [independant process scaling](http://www.12factor.net/concurrency), [isolation](http://www.12factor.net/processes) and [clean depenedency declaration and isolation](http://www.12factor.net/dependencies).

I would strongly recommend running this as two seperate processes that interact via a third party backing service.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  There is a 1-to-1 relationship between the client & server in this case, so I believe they *can* scale independently.  In fact, I don't think I want 1 server and 20 clients. I want to treat the 2 pieces of code working in unison as a single discrete, isolated unit (black box), and then simply tell Heroku, "yo, give me 10 of those."

Answer (score 1):

Heroku only lets you listen in a given port ($PORT) per dyno, I think.

I see two solutions here:

- Use Redis as a communication middleware, so the worker would write on Redis again and the listener process, instead of listening in a port would be querying redis for new jobs.
- Get another heroku dyno (or better, a complete different application) and launch there the listening process (on $PORT) and communicate both applications

Comment: The first option could work, but we'd have to open up the server & modify the code (not what I want to do, per my original post).  As for the 2nd, the other dyno would need to be locked down in terms of security.

Comment: You can have a private token shared bw/ the two apps (basic authentication)

Answer (score 1):

@makdad, is the "3rd party software" written in Ruby? If so, I would run it with a monkey patch which fakes out `TCPSocket` or whatever class it is using to access the TCP socket. Put the monkey patch in a file of its own, which will *only* be required by the Ruby process which is running the 3rd party software. The monkey patch could even read data directly from the queue, and make `TCPSocket` behave as if that data had been received.

Yes, it's not very elegant, and I'm sure there may be a better way to do it, but when are you trying to get a job done (not spend days doing research), sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and do something which is ugly, but works. Whatever solution you choose, make sure to document it for those who work on the project later.

Comment: Alex, unfortunately it isn't written in Ruby -- it is actually a compiled binary written in C++ that runs Javascript as a "command script"!