# Communicating between two processes on heroku (what port to use)

Tags: process, heroku, port, eventmachine

I have a Procfile like so:

```
web:     bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
em:      script/eventmachine
```

The `em` process fires up an eventmachine with `start_server` (port `ENV['PORT']`) and my web process occasionally needs to communicate with it.

My question is how does the web process know what port to communicate with it on?  If I understand heroku correctly it assigns you a random port when the process starts up (and it can change if the ps is killed or restarted).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes are isolated and cannot communicate directly with each other.

http://www.12factor.net/processes

There are, however, a few other ways.  One is to use a backing service such as Redis, or Postgres to act as an intermediary - another is to use FIFO to communicate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO

It is a good thing that your processes are isolated and share-nothing, but you do need to architecture your application slightly differently to accommodate this.

Comment: Yep I could do a fifo queue in redis or something, but are you sure that's about processes being unable to communicate with each other?  Eventmachine servers/clients can talk to each other over standard tcpip just like the web process accepts incoming tcpip requests.  I just don't know what port to connect on.  Thanks for the answer though - that 12factor page by Adam Wiggins is really interesting.

Comment: Yes.  Your web process is assigned a port to receive requests on from the outside world - there is no other inter process communication.  See this similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322599/tcp-socket-communication-between-processes-on-heroku-worker-dyno/9453432#9453432

Comment: Ok cool thanks, this was helpful.  I ended up using a pub/sub model with Redis which worked.  Although it's not durable, so I may try iron_mq after this and poll it from eventmachine instead.  Thanks for the help!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

According to Heroku documentation,

Two processes running *on the same dyno* can communicate over TCP/IP using whatever ports they want.

Two processes running on *different* dynos cannot communicate over TCP/IP at all. They need to use memcached, or the database, or one of the Heroku plugins, to communicate.

Comment: Current version of the documentation of this is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#networking)

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading this while on my commute to work. So I haven't tried anything with it (sorry) but this looks relevant and potentially awesome.

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/5/2/new_dyno_networking_model