# Heroku: Combining node.js and java dynos in the same app

Tags: heroku

I am building a web api service that has two components: node.js and java.
Every request reaches the node service which in turn makes an API call to the java service. I implemented this architecture using two different heroku apps, with both services implemented as "web" dynos. It works, but it will be easier to manage as a single app.

I don't fully understand what are the options and the process for combining the two components in the same application. I guess I can make two entries in the Procfile, but I don't understand how the request routing could work. How can the node "web" dyno make requests to the java dyno? Is there some mechanism for inter-dyno requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku only allows the "web" dyno to accept network connections (well, HTTP at least...). The [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) say specifically "The web process type is special as it’s the only process type that will receive HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. Other process types can be named arbitrarily."

Looking at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322599/tcp-socket-communication-between-processes-on-heroku-worker-dyno), my $.02 would be that an MQ-based solution (or something MQ-ish, like Redis pub/sub) would be the way to go. The rub is that it works best if the API call is asynchronous. For example, you could have the Node app publish to a Redis channel, and have your Java processes (defined via a 'worker' dyno in your `Procfile`). If the Node app actually needs the results as part of it's response... hm... I suppose you'd have to build something going the opposite direction, and include enough data in the message or channel structure to match up responses with the originating request.

In that case, you might just be better off sticking with the multi-app configuration. Though I have not tested the FIFO solution mentioned there, I'm not clear how it would work since the dynos are isolated from each other.

Comment: I'm staying with the multi-app configuration for now. While MQ-ish solution could work, I'd rather invest in the application itself and not the wiring right now (that's why I use Heroku :)  )