# Synchronous communication between components on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, architecture, client-server, synchronous

I'm creating a chatbot in Java for Slack which looks as follows:

[image]

*To understand this diagram, think of the "Bot" process as a Slack user that, instead of being a human, is a computer program.*

There are two components, the chatbot itself and a syntax parser. The parser takes a long time to start up, so I can't just launch the parser for each message processed by the the chatbot. Rather the parser must be always running and respond to queries from the chatbot.

I want to deploy all the components to Heroku. As far as I have seen, there are three options to deploy these components:

1. Bot and parser on the same dyno in the same application
2. Bot and parser on separate dynos in the same application
3. Bot and parser in separate applications

The question is how to best achieve a synchronous two-way communication between the two components.

So far I looked at the following possible solutions:

## Option 1: bot and parser on same dyno

- Use named pipes as shown [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/heroku/o07tFQ-qyZ0/kGKCEur1tH8J): this is an error-prone and non-portable solution
- TCP sockets (set up parser as a server and bot as a client and communicate through `localhost` and some port): this worked on AWS EC2 (through AWS Elastic Beanstalk), however, it seems to not easily work on Heroku (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322599/tcp-socket-communication-between-processes-on-heroku-worker-dyno/9453432#9453432)), and I want to migrate from AWS to Heroku

## Option 2: bot and parser on different dynos in same application

- TCP sockets: it's not a solution here, since processes running on different dynos cannot communicate with each other, as to the documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#networking)
- Third-party Heroku messaging and queueing add-on: use one of these [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons), for example, IronMQ

## Option 3: bot and parser in different applications

- Run parser as a `web` process and expose a REST interface that the chatbot can access
- Third-party Heroku messaging and queueing add-on: this should work in the same way as in Option 2

## What to do?

I would prefer to decouple the components, so I tend to Option 2 and Option 3.

A message queueing add-on would certainly work, but aren't they all targeted at **asynchronous** communication? Because I need only **synchronous** communication. There's no gain if the request to the parser returns immediately, because the bot can anyway only reply to a message when the result of the parser is available. So, asynchronous communication might be an overkill here.

Did I miss any possible solution? And what would be robust and efficient architecture for this use case?

Comment: How sure are you that you want the communication to be synchronous? It seems that the "Bot" might want to fire-and-forget the request to the "Parser", and allow the parser to make a separate request back to the Bot (possibly with a message queue in-between).

Comment: Well, the point is that the bot can't do anything useful until getting the response from the parser. Of course, I could implement this asynchronously too, but it would just come down to simulate a synchronous call with asynchronous means. So, the additional complexity of asynchronicity isn't really necessary.

Comment: Is the "read message" callback synchronous? That is, do you hold the connection open until the "send message" step?

Comment: Yes. The bot has an event handler that fires each time somebody sends a message in the Slack workspace in which the bot lives. Then there is some simple logic in the bot deciding whether the bot should react to this message or not. If yes, the bot sends the content of the message to the parser in order to get the parse tree of this message. As soon as the bot has the parse tree, it can compose a reply and send it to the Slack channel or user.